# Why can't we use push method to iterate a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to use push method to add this object arrayObject to newArrayCheck but the values property comes out as [[array] [array]] in instead of [[1,2],[5,6]]. How can I use push method to add the correct value for the value property which is [[1,2],[5,6]].

```
arrayObject =[ {
    obj : "King",
    values : [[1,2],[5,6]]
}];

newArrayCheck = []
for (let i of arrayObject){
    newArrayCheck.push(i);
};
console.log(newArrayCheck);
```

Out Put:
[image]

Comment: Your code is working as you think it is. However, `node.js` is hiding some things so that you can see the overall picture. If you want details, inspect `newArrayCheck[0]` instead, so node won't feel the need to simplify the display.

Comment: use `console.log( JSON.stringify( newArrayCheck) );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation is correct and you are allowed to do so.

You can stringify the array for quick view by console.log(JSON.stringify(newArrayCheck[0].values));

You will get the values if you iterate over the `values` property.

If you are trying to access the value use:

```
for (let obj of newArrayCheck) {
    for (let value of obj.values) {
        console.log(value)
    }
}
```

You can even use map:

```
newArrayCheck.map(obj => {
    obj.values.map(value => {
        console.log(value)
    })
})
```